# pandas: removing duplicate values in rows with same index in two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, rowwise

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['she is good', 'she is bad'], 'label':['she is good', 'she is good']})
```

I would like to compare row wise and if two same-indexed rows have the same values, replace the duplicate in the 'label' column with the word 'same'.

Desired output:

```
           pos        label
0  she is good      same

1   she is bad  she is good
```

so far, i have tried the following, but it returns an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)

df['label'] =np.where(df.query("text == label"), df['label']== ' ',df['label']==df['label'] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, have a look at the documentation of [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).
Check for equality between your two columns, and replace the values in your label column:

```
import numpy as np
df['label'] = np.where(df['text'].eq(df['label']),'same',df['label'])
```

prints:

```
          text        label
0  she is good         same
1   she is bad  she is good
```